Avy keybindings
I would like to define keybindings for avy - more precisely, let's say I call one of the avy-goto-... functions, now these all expect a character. I would like to be able to have a keybinding (e.g M-' or whatever) that calls another function.
The problem is that since a char is expected, any keybinding I press just leads to a "Wrong type of argument" error. Furthermore, I would like the keybinding to be specific to avy (and not global).
Some approaches I tried:

Wrap avy with a function that intercepts the key stroke (does not work, "non-character input event")
A wrapper that defines a transient key map -> not elegant and also did not work

Any ideas perhaps? Ideally I would be able to define an "avy-map" but since there isn't an avy-minor-mode when avy is active and expecting a char, this is not possible
